# changing shortcut keys

Tags: sound, keyboard

Since two days, I am the proud owner of a Lubuntu operating system. When I press the space key on my desktop, I want it to pause the audio that I am playing. Instead, it lowers the page that I am currently in. How can I change this? Also, I would like to change the keyboard settings in order to be able to make a "é" by first pressing ' and then e. When I do that now it just becomes 'e instead of é.

Comment: Please limit your question to just one issue only. I've edited your question to remove the bluetooth aspect. You may please ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Also, please mention the version of Lubuntu.

Comment: You want the space key to always pause the audio? Probably not. If not, then be specific in what cases you want the space key to serve to pause the audio. Currently, you refer to "pressing the space key on your desktop", which is not very precise.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I would like it to pause the music when I am playing music, a podcast or a video on a website. When I write, I would like it to do what is is supposed to do :)  (i.e. notwritingsentenceslikethis)